# Is there a way to find where a webform in wordpress is being sent to?

Tags: wordpress

I have a website I adopted in my new role, I haven't touched much webdev work since undergrad in 2011.
Anywho, the site is in wordpress. I have access to the word press admin, I also have access to what appears to be a mySQL instance. Question is, is there a way to see if webforms on this site post data to the mySQL server I have access to? Or anyway to see where it is sending this data?

I have identified the form fields and tried searching both mySQL tables and the wordpress site for the field names and nothing comes up!

Comment: note: the mySQL DB is on a centOS server, which I also have access to. I have the root credentials for the DB and the CentOS login info.

Comment: Why do you need to know exactly where in the database the forms are being saved?

Comment: Are there any form plugins being used?

Comment: @kmoser - we have a request to add someone to a form selection field. I need to find the table add the new person as an option

Comment: no form plug-ins being used (on WP admin, we had gravity forms way back - but I did just find myPHPadmin and was able to login, exploring this now. Still can't find the form field I need, all the tables don't match with the one I need.

Comment: WP also does not show the forms in the forms list when logged in as WP admin, there is just one form, a feedback form. This is not what I need access to.

Comment: One doesn't usually edit a Wordpress form directly in the DB. There must be a place where you can edit that info on an admin page of some sort. Unfortunately without access to the admin page there's not much more I can recommend.

Comment: Try debuging $_POST when u submit the form. If its email form debug with wp_mail(). Its weird to not know if its form from a plugin or its built in the theme itself. If its part of the theme go to theme documentation for more info or ask devs ?